# Anytime Picker: Month table is not in a table form, but its inline downwards

Tags: javascript, css, anytime

im using the current css and js from http://www.ama3.com/anytime/

Basically the month table is not suppose to look like this. Some how it displays inline downwards. Can i get some help with this. Im thinking it should be the CSS that is the problem. Thanks

anytime.5.0.5.css
anytime.5.0.5.js

See here:
[image]

```
String selectTime ="chooseTime";

var anytimeFormat = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s";
var anytimeFormatConverter = new AnyTime.Converter({format:anytimeFormat}); 

AnyTime.picker( "<%=selectTime%>", { 
    format: anytimeFormat, 
    firstDOW: 1
});

<input id="chooseTime" name="chooseTime" type="text" maxlength="16" size="16" value=""> &nbsp;(DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss)<br />
```

Comment: I have tested and it work properly. In your css try search for `.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-mon-btn` and see if it have `float: left;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems like that are typically caused by a missing or incorrect DOCTYPE declaration. Did you try following the Troubleshooting Tips at http://www.ama3.com/anytime/#tips ?

For faster help, please email me by clicking Contact in the menu at the top of that page.

Comment: I realised I placed it in a <li> container with clear: both in it. Causing the problem. Thanks for the response and awesome anytime picker!